# How to parse data in a text file?

Tags: data-sets, filesystems

I had a question about altering a text file. I have data in the following format.

```
1 a,b,c
2 d,e
3 a, l, m,n
```

**Note that some of them have spaces after the coma**

Now I have to resort the data in the following format

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 d 
2 e
3 a
3 l
3 m 
3 n
```

Now my plan is to first parse the data, and hold a count of how many data elements there are for each number. (Ex. for the number 1, there are 3 elements).
Then I would move down the data by 3 spaces, starting from the bottom. Kinda like moving an array. (The main concern here is space more than time complexity)

Then I would enter each data element at the top.

My first question is, how exactly would I parse the data in a txt file and indicate delimiters such as the coma and the possible spaces.

Second, having done this, how would I just move down a whole line inside a text file down one?

I am very sorry if my question is convoluted. I will gladly clarify anything. Thank you so much for your time! Please let me know if there is anything i need to add. Also, I'm comfortable in both java and c. So advice on either language is useful.

Comment: This is more a case for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this, more direct to code (in java, c, etc.)

- read each line (until CR/LF)
- at begining, read a number, until spaces => number n
- after that, take next characters of line
- split them by ,
- for each, trim (delete space before or after) => strings s1, s2, s3
- then output n s1  CRLF n s2 CRLF n s3, etc.